# Why doesn't Nick Fury travel with security force?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier, nick-fury

In *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*,

> Nick Fury’s vehicle is attacked by a group of mercenaries, who immobilize and destroy his vehicle. He has no apparent security force with the vehicle to protect him.

Nick Fury is a director of S.H.I.E.L.D. who has top level privileges, so he is a VIP or VVIP. Why weren't there security forces to protect him?

Comment: Not everybody watches the trailer (or deliberately avoids it, to go in completely fresh), so “it’s in the trailer” doesn’t avoid it being a spoiler. (Albeit a lesser one than previous questions.)

Comment: @alexwlchan Ha.. Ha.. So, you did downvote again?

Comment: no down vote from me this time, since you’d clearly put some thought into spoilers this time.

Comment: @alexwlchan - sorry, that's over the line. Something that's in the trailer (or first minutes of the movie) is generally NOT considered a "spoiler" by most people, including those who deal with spoilers professionally (like Honest Trailers or CinemaSins crews).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Three reasons I can think of:

1. At this point in the movie, Fury already:

   > suspects SHIELD is compromised.

   He is calling Hill securely to meet in secret and this sets up her appearance later.  He is traveling under the radar to meet Hill and hence, no entourage.
2. Fury knows that

   > the [STRIKE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.T.R.I.K.E.) team is one of the most compromised units, it is entirely likely that the people attacking Fury in this scene *are his security detail*, or comprised of people who might be assigned as his security detail.
3. Finally: He doesn't need one.  He is a maverick agent who has survived countless encounters and is armed to the teeth with SHIELD tech.  While it might seem at first blush that the scene proves he *does* need one - it seems the opposite when you consider:

   > he escapes an ambush, decimates the opposing force and manages to elude The Winter Soldier, one of history's most legendary assassins.

Comment: btw, by "maverick" I mean "one who went up the ranks with field experience" - not "cool rogue pilot".  Which is, for the record, the more authentic use for the term I think.

Comment: But what about *this* [Maverick](http://marvel.com/universe/Maverick_%28Chris_Bradley%29)?

Comment: He was in an armed, armoured, flying car. What more could a couple of guards have done?

Comment: @Richard Died valiantly defending him?

Comment: @Keen - That sounds like a really bad day at the office.